# updating array object in mongodb using Nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my saved document

```
"_id": ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111"),
"isApproved": false,
"vendorOrder": [ 
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95113"), 
    "publicationCode": "TOI", 
    "publicationName": "Times of India", 
    "editionName": "chennai city", 
    "productCode": "TCE1", 
    "subscriptionCopies": 70, 
    "tradeCopies": 40
  }, 
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95112"), 
    "publicationCode": "ET", 
    "publicationName": "Economic Times", 
    "editionName": "chennai city", 
    "productCode": "ECE1", 
    "subscriptionCopies": 20, 
    "tradeCopies": 100
  }
],
"frequency": "TH",
"orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1"),
"submittedTo": ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"),
```

Here is my mongo shell query:

```
db.orders.updateOne(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111"),
    "submittedTo":ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"), 
    "vendorOrder.productCode": "TCE1"
  },
  { $set:{"vendorOrder.$.tradeCopies":80 }
})
```

**But**, only one element is getting updated **MOREOVER** this `query` is not working in nodejs.

**Nodejs query:**

```
const { orderId, dealerId, productCode, tradeCopies } = req.body;
try {
  const orders = await Order.updateOne(
    {
      _id: orderId,
      submittedTo: dealerId,
      vendorOrder.productCode: productCode
    }, { 
      $set: { vendorOrder.$.tradeCopies: tradeCopies } 
    }
  )
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex);
}
```

**Goal is to update** the `vendorOrder:[{tradeCopies}]` of all the elements in one go unique code is Product Code i.e i want to upadate `tradeCopies` in `vendorOrder` where `productCode`, `orderId`, `dealerId` would come from `req.body` and `tradeCopies` should get updated against the `productCodes`.

Answer (score 0):

To update all elements ("tradeCopies" field) in the array matching a condition on the array element field ("productCode") you must use the `$arrayFilters` update option. This can be done both in Mongo Shell as well as the NodeJS driver's API method call `updateOne`.

Mongo Shell version:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111"), submittedTo:ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2") },
   { $set: { "vendorOrder.$[elem].tradeCopies" : 80 } },
   {
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.productCode": "TCE1" } ]
   }
)
```

The NodeJS version:

```
col.updateOne( { _id: orderId, submittedTo: dealerId,  }, 
               { $set: { "vendorOrder.$[elem].tradeCopies" : 80 } }, 
               { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.productCode": "TCE1" } ] }, 
               function( err, result ) {
                   console.log(result);
               }
);
```

[ Edit - Add ]

Using the async / await syntax the query will be like this (for details see [MongoDB NodeJS driver update examples](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/)):

```
result = await coll.updateOne( { ... }, { $set: { ... } }, { arrayFilters: [ { ...} ] } );
```

Comment: ,thanks its working in shell but not in node and is it possible to update all the "tradeCopies" field in vendorOrder with respect to their "productCode" i.e from frontend i wud get multiple "productCodes":["TCE1","ECE1","STE1"] and i need to update tradeCopies against these productCodes in one go... i am kind of stuck in this usecase

Comment: async await is added its giving 200 from postman, but modified is :0 i also tried removing "" quotes but vs code shows error and same query is working in shell

Comment: _"thanks its working in shell but not in node."_: The  approach to update in the shell is the way you have to update in the NodeJS driver's code too, it is the same syntax; see [updateOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/Collection.html#updateOne). I don't know why you are getting errors with Node's code.

Comment: okay but can we update all the tradeCopies with respect to their productCodes in one go coz req.body will get multiple productCodes at the same time